# Can I put a hanger derailleur on a direct mount frame?

Tags: derailleur-rear

I have a road bicycle whose threads for the direct mount derailleur are stripped in the frame.

Is it possible to use a hanger derailleur instead? Are there other options?

Comment: Do you have a slotted drop-out for the axle to fit into or is it  a semi circular notch?

Comment: @mikes It's slotted, similar to [this one](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/42/Rear_dropout.JPG/220px-Rear_dropout.JPG) (but not single speed).

Comment: If it's a nice enough frame, you could also find a local frame builder who could braze on a new hanger to replace the stripped one.

Comment: To help clarify, I don't think direct mount is the right term. From your photo, it looks like a steel frame with a derailleur hanger forged on the dropout. It's not a "replaceable" hanger as you would find on newer bikes, but a hanger none the less (the derailleur "hangs" from it). Direct mount is a whole other beast created a few years ago to stiffen up the connection from bike to derailleur. So I believe you're asking if you can use a replaceable hanger in place of your fixed one. I don't know of any. Your best options are the helicoil or dropout saver or as I said brazing on a new hanger.

Comment: @NoahSutherland The OP is asking if they can use a claw-type derailer on a frame with a conventional non-replaceable hanger. "Direct mount" has been in use to describe the conventional attachment type as opposed to claw type for a very long time, far longer than the new standard called by the same name has existed. Wholesale catalogs used the term this way, for example.

Answer (score 6):

Usually it's fixable either via helical insert (Helicoil) or a threaded sleeve called a dropout saver.

[image: Dropout Saver]
Dropout Saver

[image: Helical Insert]

Helical Insert

The Helicoil approach gives a neater result. It requires either having an expensive tool (an M10x1 Helicoil kit) or paying a shop to do it.

Dropout Savers are somewhat quick and dirty. They have the very trivial disadvantage that because they're essentially a nut for the derailer bolt, you may need another wrench to install or remove the derailer. But they work fine and are the cheap solution to this problem, especially if you want to fix it at home. They come in different widths.

Answer (score 0):

SunRace makes a universal hanger. Its' primary use is to install a modern derailleur on an older frame. The SunRace part # is DP1071. It may fit your frame depending on the dropout shape. A Google search shows they are available from a variety of sellers for under $5 US.